# R tibble: Group by column A, keep only distinct values in column B and C and sum values in column C

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, distinct, summarize

I want to group by column `A` and then sum values in column `C` for distinct values in columns `B` and `C`. Is it possible to do it inside `summarise` clause? 
I know that's possible with `distinct()` function before aggregation. What about something like that:
Data:

```
df <- tibble(A = c(1,1,1,2,2), B = c('a','b','b','a','a'), C=c(5,10,10,15,15))
```

My try that doesn't work:

```
df %>% 
group_by(A) %>% 
summarise(sumC=sum(distinct(B,C) %>% select(C)))
```

Desired ouput:

```
A sumC
1 15
2 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `duplicated`

```
df %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    summarise(sumC = sum(C[!duplicated(B)]))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#      A  sumC
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    15
#2     2    15
```

Or with `distinct`

```
df %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    distinct(B, C) %>%
    summarise(sumC = sum(C))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#      A  sumC
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    15
#2     2    15
```

Answer (score 0):

A different possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(A, B, C) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 group_by(A) %>%
 summarise(sumC = sum(C))

      A  sumC
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    15
2     2    15
```

Or a twist on @Maurits Evers answer:

```
df %>%
 distinct(A, B, C) %>%
 group_by(A) %>%
 summarise(sumC = sum(C))
```